# Writing into pipe always fails

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe, fork

I am trying to communicate between 2 processes by trying to read data from text file into first pipe and read it on the other one but the write function always fails:

**Main:**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int readerPip[2], writerPip[2], reader, writer;

    if (pipe(readerPip))
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Pipe failed.\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if(pipe(writerPip))
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Pipe failed.\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    close(readerPip[1]); // closing reader writing side pipe for main thread
    reader = fork();
    if (reader < 0)
    {
        perror("Cannot fork()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (reader == 0)
    {
        do_reader(readerPip);
    }

    wait(NULL);
    close(writerPip[0]); // closing writer reader side pipe for main thread
    do_father(readerPip, writerPip);
    close(readerPip[0]); // closing reader reader side pipe for main thread
    close(writerPip[1]); // closing writer writing side pipe for main thread
    writer = fork();

    if (writer < 0)
    {
        perror("Cannot fork()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (writer == 0)
    {
        do_writer(writerPip);
    }

    return 1;
}// main
```

**do_Reader:**

```
void do_reader(int readerPipe[])
{
    char stringCommand[17];
    long long unsigned command;

    close(readerPipe[0]);
    while (1)
    {
        scanf("%s", stringCommand);
        command = convertStringToPolygon(stringCommand);

        if ((command & 0xFFFFFFFF) == 0xFFFFFFFF)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (write(readerPipe[1], stringCommand, strlen(stringCommand) ) == -1)
        {
            printf("writing falied");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("success");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    close(readerPipe[1]);
    exit(0);
}
```

**do_father**

```
void do_father(int readerPipe[], int writerPipe[])
{
    long long unsigned nbytes;
    char currentPolygon[17];
    currentPolygon[16] = '\0';
    while (1)
    {
        nbytes = read(readerPipe[0], currentPolygon, sizeof(currentPolygon));
        if (nbytes == 0)
        {
            printf("done");
            break;
        }

        manageProgram(readerPipe, writerPipe,        convertStringToCommand(currentPolygon));
    }
}
```

**do_writer**

```
void do_writer(int pip[])
{
    close(pip[1]);
    long long unsigned command, nbytes;

    while (1)
    {
    nbytes = read(pip[0], &command, sizeof(command));
        if (nbytes == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        if ((((command & THIRD_BIT_MASK) != FALSE) || ((command & FORTH_BIT_MASK) 
!= FALSE) ||
            ((command & FIFTH_BIT_MASK) != FALSE)) != FALSE)
            generateOutputDependsOnBits(command);
    }

    close(pip[0]);
    exit(0);
}
```

the rest of the code does not matter since writing for the reader pipe does not working.
the text file looks like this:

> 3a
>   0000050000050505
>   3e
>   003cc40000c43c3c
>   ba
>   000088ec9c32ce32
>   f8
>   cc
>   3a
>   000085ec9a32cd32
>   4c
>   8c
>   5c
>   ac
>   fd
>   FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Comment: asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, please post a [mcve]  so we can re-create the problem, so we can help you debug it.

Comment: OT:  For ease of readability and understanding:  1) separate code blocks: `for `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  2) consistently indent the code.  Indent after EVERY opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: where/what are the functions: `do_write()` and `do_father()`

Comment: the `fork()` function has three returned indications:  >0 indicates parent process =0 indicates child process <0 indicates an error occurred.  The code should be checking/handling all 3 conditions

Comment: the returned value from the function: `fork()` is defined as a `pid_t`  Currently, that is an alias for `int`, but you cannot depend on that alias

Comment: do_father() reads from the reader pipe and write it to the writer pipe
do_writer() reads from the writer pipe and printing the data to out.log file @user3629249

Comment: where is the code for those functions?

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`  Since those parameters are not being used, the compiler will output two warning messages.  Suggest using the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: for ease of readability and documentation, follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: added the 2 missing functions.
@user3629249

Comment: to communicate (one way) between two processes, only a single pipe() is needed.  The process that will write to the pipe should close the read end of the pipe.  The process that will read from the pipe should close the write end of the pipe

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s", stringCommand);`  when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the input format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]', Always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer.  This is because those input specifiers always append a NUL byte to the end of the input.  This avoids any possibility of buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Comment: OT:in function: `do_writer()`,  IT does not perform an writing!  It does perform a read from a pipe.  So the function name seems to be misleading

Comment: regarding: `  nbytes = read(pip[0], &command, sizeof(command));
  
        if (nbytes == 0)
        {
            break;
        }`  what about when the `read()` function returns a value less than 0?   The returned type from `read()` is a `ssize_t`, not a `long long unsigned` type.  This needs to be corrected.

Comment: do_writer is writing to the output.
@user3629249

Comment: what is the definition of: `THIRD_BIT_MASK` and `FORTH_BIT_MASK` and `FIFTH_BIT_MASK`  It would be clearer to actually define those masks at the place they are used, (unless they may be changing)

Comment: THIRD_BIT_MASK and FORTH_BIT_MASK and FIFTH_BIT_MASK are consts by define
@user3629249

Comment: So, where are those `#define` statements.  You really need to post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem, so we can help you debug it.

Comment: #define THIRD_BIT_MASK 0x08
#define FORTH_BIT_MASK 0x10
#define FIFTH_BIT_MASK 0x20

@user3629249

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `fprintf (stderr, "Pipe failed.\n");`  This is not helpful to the user of your program.  When an error indication is returned from a C library function any error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred should both be output to `stderr`.  A very good way to do that is to call `perror()`

Comment: in function: `do_reader()` an error path is causing the execution of: `exit(0)`  However, 0 is typically used to indicate 'success' but the function failed  This should be corrected

Comment: regarding: `if (write(readerPipe[1], stringCommand, strlen(stringCommand) ) == -1)`  What about when it returns 0?  Also, the 'desired' returned value is `strlen(stringCommand)`  The posted code is assuming that the `write()` was successful if the returned value is not -1.  That is kind of a stretch

Comment: in function: `do_reader()`  it is executing: `close(readerPipe[1]);`, but that is already performed in `main()`.  Closing a pipe that is already closed is an error

Comment: do_reader is a method that only a child process will preform therefore he needs to close his sides of the pipe and the pipe close in main points on the main process therefore there are two closing - one for each process
@user3629249

Comment: the `main()` function is closing one end of each pipe before `fork()` is called, so the child processes cannot perform the desired `read()` or `write()` because the needed end of the pipe is already closed

Answer (score 1):

You close `readpipe[1]` in `main` (*before* the `fork`) and close `readpipe[0]` in `do_reader`, so *both* sides of the pipe are closed in the child.

Move the `close(readpipe[1])` in `main` farther down (e.g. before the `wait`).

But, you may not want to `wait` there. You may want to do it after `do_father` as this would rely upon the kernel pipe buffers being large enough to hold *all* the data the child sends to the parent before the parent even tries to get the first byte.

Comment: the same problem also occurs with `writepipe[]

Comment: so the wait function should be right before i am closing the reader pipe of the main process?